# java.sql.sqlexception invalid column index while insert

Tags: java, sql, insert

I have a sql statement that runs fine in a DB and doesn't show any errors in the Dataset and Query Dialog but when I hit the "Read Fields" button it throws the error 
"Invalid Column Index"

my sql code

```
--Employees TABLE
create table employee1 (    
ssn number(4)  PRIMARY KEY,
ename VARCHAR2(20),
eposition VARCHAR2(30),
dname VARCHAR2(30) ,
salary number (8) ,
phoneNo number(16)   not null, 
dateOfBirth  date  not null,
grade VARCHAR(1),


CONSTRAINT Dname_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(dname) 
REFERENCES department1(dname) ON DELETE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT salgrade_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(grade) 
REFERENCES salgrade1(grade) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

my java code

```
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                    String sql = "insert into employee1(ssn,ename,eposition,dname,salary, phoneNo, dateOfBirth, grade) VALUES (?,'?','?','?',?,?,'?','?')";
                    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                stmt.setString(1, ssn.getText());
                stmt.setString(2, eename.getText());
                stmt.setString(3, eepos.getText());
                stmt.setString(4, dname.getText());
                stmt.setString(5, salary.getText());
                stmt.setString(6, phone.getText());
                stmt.setString(7, dob.getText());
                stmt.setString(8, garde1.getText());
                //stmt.executeUpdate(); 


                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                    int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "DO YOU WANT TO SAVE ?", "SELECT YES OR NO",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (x == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        conn.commit();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD SAVED");
                    } else {
                        conn.rollback();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO RECORDS ARE SAVED");
                    }
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

any idea ?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the question marks in the `insert` statement.

Comment: I tried that before, when I remove it I got this error.                                                  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: You are trying to pas string to an int field.

Comment: I solved the problem ..the issue in the date (use **To_Date**  function) …